# JSON Parsing Error while creating HIVE table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

Firstly, I am new to Hive.

I fetched twitter data through apache flume.

```
{
"filter_level": "low",
"retweeted": false,
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"possibly_sensitive": false,
"truncated": false,
"lang": "en",
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"id": 756378998838530048,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
"timestamp_ms": "1469169780822",
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"created_at": "Fri Jul 22 06:43:00 +0000 2016",
"favorite_count": 0,
"place": null,
"coordinates": null,
"text": "#furry pokemon sex mermaid sex position",
"contributors": null,
"geo": null,
"entities": {
    "symbols": [],
    "urls": [{
        "expanded_url": "http://14.gerase.tk",
        "indices": [40, 63],
        "display_url": "14.gerase.tk",
        "url": ""
    }],
    "hashtags": [{
        "text": "furry",
        "indices": [0, 6]
    }],
    "user_mentions": []
},
"is_quote_status": false,
"source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client<\/a>",
"favorited": false,
"in_reply_to_user_id": null,
"retweet_count": 0,
"id_str": "756378998838530048",
"user": {
    "location": null,
    "default_profile": true,
    "statuses_count": 3436,
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "lang": "ru",
    "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
    "id": 752318303280955392,
    "following": null,
    "favourites_count": 0,
    "protected": false,
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "verified": false,
    "description": null,
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "name": "Мария Виноградова",
    "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
    "created_at": "Mon Jul 11 01:47:15 +0000 2016",
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "followers_count": 5,
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/753398763201425408/X_2mAGt1_normal.jpg",
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "profile_background_image_url": "",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "url": null,
    "utc_offset": null,
    "time_zone": null,
    "notifications": null,
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "friends_count": 21,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "screen_name": "afinafedorova2",
    "id_str": "752318303280955392",
    "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/753398763201425408/X_2mAGt1_normal.jpg",
    "listed_count": 5,
    "is_translator": false
}
```

}

I am using HiveJSONSerDe  as mentioned in https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example
And this is the Hive Query I am trying to Run.

```
create external table twitterdata(
filter_level string,
retweeted boolean,
in_reply_to_screen_name string,
possibly_sensitive boolean,
trauncated boolean,
lang string,
in_reply_to_status_id_str string,
id bigint,
in_reply_to_user_id_str string,
timestamp_ms string,
in_reply_to_status_id int,
created_at string,
favourite_count int,
place string,
coordinates string,
text string,
contributors string,
geo string,
entities STRUCT<
        urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING,url:STRING>>,
    hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>,
        user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>>,
is_quote_status boolean,
source string,
favotited boolean,
in_reply_to_user_id int,
retweet_count int,
id_str string,
user STRUCT<
    location:STRING,
    default_profile:boolean,
    statuses_count:int,
    profile_background_tile:boolean,
    lang: string,
    profile_link_color: string,
    id: bigint,
    following: string,
    protected: boolean,
    profile_text_color: string,
    verified: boolean,
    description: string,
    contributors_enabled: boolean,
    name: string,   
    created_at: string,
    default_profile_image: boolean,
    followers_count: int,
    profile_image_url_https: string,
    geo_enabled: boolean
    url: string,
    time_zone: string,
    friends_count: int,
    screen_name: string,
    id_str: string,
    listed_count: int,
    is_translator: boolean>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/Twitter/Pokemon/';
```

But It is showing an error about parsing the JSON script.

```
FAILED: Parse Error: line 31:2 mismatched input 'location' expecting identifier in column specification
```

I cannot find out the mistakes in that create table query. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at that line in the data file. It's most likely that your JSON file isn't intact or doesn't match the schema.

If you're looking to continuously load data to a hive table you may want to also check out  [StreamSets](https://streamsets.com/opensource). You can use it to capture JSON data, automatically convert to Avro and populate and update a hive table.

*Full disclosure, I'm a committer on the project.*

Comment: Actually, "location" itself is a keyword in hive, that cannot be used as any attribute name. Sorry, I forgot edit my question. :)